# Knight on the keyboard

Tags: word, no-computers, chess, open-ended, knight-moves

You are given a QWERTY keyboard, and are allowed to choose where you wish to start. You are only able type in the same way a knight is able to move on a chessboard (but in this case, on the keyboard).

**What is the largest proper English word you can make?**

```
 ┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
 | Q | W | E | R | T | Y | U | I | O | P |
 └─┬─┴─┬─┴─┬─┴─┬─┴─┬─┴─┬─┴─┬─┴─┬─┴─┬─┴─┬─┘
   | A | S | D | F | G | H | J | K | L |
   └─┬─┴─┬─┴─┬─┴─┬─┴─┬─┴─┬─┴─┬─┴─┬─┴───┘
     | Z | X | C | V | B | N | M |
     └───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
(Thanks to GOTO 0's post for the keyboard)
```

For some clarification, when moving move the 3 spaces left or right, the knight will turn onto the furthest key. When moving up or down, you can go to either side.

> Examples:
>
> **(left or right):**
>
> A->(R or C) and not E or X
>
> G->(E or X/ I or M) and not R or C
>
> **(up or down):**
>
> W->(Z or C/ F) to clarify vertical movement: [W-S-X->Z or C]
>
> V->(U or T or E/ S or J) to clarify vertical movement: [V-G-Y->T or U or E]

Comment: `V->(T or U)` would E be allowed as well?

Comment: @Bob Yes, both initial directions are allowed. I only showed one to keep the examples small.

Comment: For real clarification, you should instead extend the examples instead of keeping them small.

Comment: How about two letters in a row?

Comment: Can N go to L? In chess, at least, you don't have to move 2-then-1, you can move 1-then-2 (although I don't think it matters on a chessboard because it's regular). So can I go N -> J -> K -> L?

Comment: I just searched through all 58,000 words on http://www.mieliestronk.com/wordlist.html and only found 4 letter matches.  There are at most 17 but ive not checked them all.

Comment: If **A** can go to **R**, then that means we should think of the top row being shifted 0.5 keys _left_. But then you say **G** can go to **E**, which suggests we should think of the top row being shifted 0.5 keys _right_.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because without defining "word" it turns into an ill-defined, open-ended puzzle (and [open-ended puzzles are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) as of May 2019)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't beat six, unless I'm allowed to use an exotic animal:

> Caracara, with 8 letters.

Then here are the old, invalid answers that I'm keeping here so the comments make sense. =P

Seven letter exotic animals: caracal, aracari
Other six-letter words: carhop, unfull

I will admit I wrote a program for this, though I think I did it before the no-computers tag popped up (or at least I didn't see it). Also apparently it was a bad program since it gave me several invalid answers!

Comment: L is not reachable from A and I is not reachable from R, so both your 7-letter animals are invalid. And you can't reach P from O, so carhop is also invalid.

Comment: My goodness, I really screwed the pooch on this one. Should have double checked my work! I'll leave these up as a testament to carelessness. =P

Comment: Am I right that LL is cheating?

Comment: 8-letter word, though?  That's pretty good.

Comment: Could you edit this to stress that Caracara is the answer?  It is the only valid word here but the best one anyone has found.

Answer (score 3):

The best I can find has 4

> Arch

Answer (score 2):

So far, I've only been able to find some 4-letter words:

> Carb: **C**, C-X-Z -> **A**, A-S-D -> **R**, R-F-V -> **B** 
>  Gimp: **G**, G-H-J -> **I**, I-J-N -> **M**, M-K-O -> **P** 
>  Bibi: **B**, B-H-U -> **I**, I-J-N -> **B**, B-H-U -> **I**

Answer (score 1):

I swear I didn't use the other answer! (6)

> Archon

Answer (score 1):

My Score is 4

This is how I understand the rules (the letter before the colon can reach each letter after the colon in 1 move):

```
N:T,F,U,O,L
C:W,A,R,Y,H
Q:D,X
J:T,P,V
F:W,U,Z,N
K:Y,B
P:J,M
U:F,V,N,L
O:H,N
Y:D,C,B,K,M
B:R,D,Y,I,K
I:G,B,M
E:X,G,V
H:R,O,C
T:S,X,V,J,N
W:Z,F,C
R:A,Z,C,H,B
M:Y,G,I,P
V:E,S,T,U,J
X:Q,E,T,G
D:Q,Y,B
Z:W,R,F
S:T,V
L:U,N
A:R,C
G:E,I,X,M
```

Despite the no-computers tag, I was curious if it's really that hard to find words. It seems to be: Trying this against the word list in /usr/share/dict/words under linux with almost 100k english words only got these (omitting anything below 4 letters):

> RACY ARCH LUVS LULU CARA MIMI